Руководство для новых пользователей Stack Overflow на русском
Месяц начинается с первого числа, день недели с понедельника, а начало работы со Stack Overflow начинается с ознакомления с правилами. По-хорошему вы должны были ознакомиться с ними нажав на "Справка и прочие ресурсы" (значок вопроса в верхнем правом углу), но мы подозреваем, что в таком случае вас бы не отправили на данную страницу, не так ли?
Итак, мы представляем вашему вниманию сборник одних из самых частых вопросов-ответов, которые пригодятся новым пользователям этого сайта, пропустившим вкладку "Справка".

Чем вызвана необходимость этой темы? Судя по тону, вы собираете ссылку на это кидать новичкам? Тут как-то слишком много в одном ответе и похоже дублирует то, что уже есть в справке или на мете. Руководства на мете нужны для того, чего нет в справке, и они должны быть более узкими.

@MSDN.WhiteKnight, вы правы, это является целью. Зачастую редакторам/проверяющим приходится предоставлять различные ссылки под вопросами/ответами. Я подумал, что хорошей идеей было бы собрать всё воедино (тем более ссылки на оригиналы статей имеются). К тому же в этой статье приведено немало уточнений по каждому из вопросов.

Кому не лень читать - сам может пролистать статьи из справки. Кому лень - наверное не осилит и это...

Итак, начнём наше турне (большинство заголовков кликабельно):
1. На какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы и какие вопросы лучше не задавать?
Начнём с того, что:

Stack Overflow на русском — это сайт вопросов и ответов для профессиональных разработчиков программного обеспечения, энтузиастов программирования и системных администраторов. Сайт создан и управляется сообществом. С вами вместе мы создаём свободную библиотеку подробных ответов на любой прикладной вопрос по программированию и системному администрированию.

Какие же темы неуместны на Stack Overflow на русском?
Итак, вы не можете:

Задавать неуместные вопросы не по теме (даже если они касаются обсуждений в сфере IT);
Просить сделать за вас "бесплатную" работу — Stack Overflow не про фриланс;
Просить сделать за вас домашнее задание;
Спрашивать: "Какой язык программирования/фреймворк/библиотека лучше: X или Y?" или "Я начал изучать/создавать/программировать на X. Что вы можете посоветовать?" — на вопросы такого рода содержится уже достаточно ответов со сборником всех нужных книг, документаций и мануалов — поищите их на ruSO;
Пытаться задать необъективный вопрос или породить расширенную дискуссию — этот сайт не место для таких вопросов;
Писать: "Вот код, он не работает, что не так?" — вы должны поставить конкретную задачу с конкретной проблемой (предоставьте текст ошибки, строку, на которой она возникает, по возможности входные и выходные данные);
Задавать вопрос без конкретики — играть в сочинителя на этом сайте не нужно, ровно как и приводить историю создания вашего приложения "от А до Я" (за исключением глубоко продуманных вопросов, связанных с оптимизацией архитектуры и т. п., которые могут быть важны и полезны для этого сайта);
Публиковать вопрос/ответ на иностранном языке — лингвистов на сайте Stack Overflow на русском не так много, ваш вопрос/ответ не будут переводить, а скорее всего закроют/удалят. Помните об этом! Для других языков есть свои сайты Stack.

Не забывайте, что Stack Overflow это не форум.
2. Как задать хороший вопрос?
Хороший вопрос:

Содержит понятный заголовок;
Понятен, грамотно написан как с точки зрения правил русского языка, так и с точки зрения терминов программирования (во избежание двусмысленности);
Визуально приятно читать;
Представляет собой минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример (подробнее в пункте 7 руководства);
Наполнен подробностями описания вашей проблемы, ваших действий, входными и выходными данными, ожидаемым и фактическим поведением проблемного кода;
Требует решения конкретной проблемы;
Содержит подходящие по теме проблемы метки;
Уникален (не является дубликатом уже существующего вопроса);
Соблюдает пункты 4, 5, 6 и 7 данного руководства.

Хороший вопрос позволяет другому человеку, столкнувшемуся с аналогичной проблемой, сказать: "А у меня также! Жизненно!" (по поводу этого: важен один нюанс, о котором будет сказано в пункте 9 руководства).

Также старайтесь избегать в вашем вопросе "Ошибки XY" — это ситуация, когда ваш вопрос включает в себя несколько несвязанных между собой подвопросов, которые затрудняют понимание проблемы.

Как бы вы не удивлялись, но возможность задать вопрос это не право, а привилегия на Stack Overflow.
Не верите? Убедитесь в этом сами в соответствующей статье создателей Stack Overflow.
Цитата (с переводом):

Мы считаем, что задавать вопросы на нашем сайте — это привилегия, а не право. Если после нескольких честных попыток вы не смогли доказать, что ваш вклад в определенный Stack Exchange делает его по крайней мере... не хуже... то мы оставляем за собой право отклонить ваши вопросы. Если мы не сделаем свою часть работы по отсеиванию плохих вопросов, то мы рискуем оттолкнуть настоящих экспертов, которые дают то, что действительно важно: ответы!
<...>
Возможно, вы уловили суть. Входящие вопросы — это универсальная константа, вокруг нас их бесчисленные миллиарды. Но ответы — действительно блестящие, удивительные, правильные ответы — так же редки как жемчужины. Таким образом, вопросы — это всего лишь песок, который производит жемчужины. Если мы чему-то и научились за последние три года, так это тому, что нужно оптимизировать для жемчужин, а не для песка.

Задавать вопрос нужно не с целью решения вашей конкретной проблемы, а с целью пополнения базы знаний.
Если вам хочется задать вопрос и получить на него ответ, а другие люди вас не волнуют — то это неверный подход. Мизантропия на этом сайте "не в почёте".

Чтобы вам было проще это осознать, представьте себя на месте писателя книги — вам же хочется, чтобы ваше произведение читали, любили и о нём все знали повсеместно, не правда ли?
3. Как написать хороший ответ?
Хороший вопрос требует не менее хорошего ответа! Не забывайте соблюдать предыдущие пункты данного списка при написании ответа.
Однако даже если ваш ответ полезен, не стоит отвечать если:

Вопрос с той же проблематикой уже задавался ранее (является "дубликатом") — вместо ответа на этот вопрос поставьте тревогу: "Тревога" → "Необходимо улучшить" → "Дубликат" → укажите ссылку на аналогичный вопрос, заданный ранее → "Поставить тревогу на вопросе". Вы не сможете поставить тревогу по причине "дубликат", если на вопрос другого автора не был дан ответ;
Задан вопрос по типу описанного в пункте 1 руководства;
Ваш вопрос является догадкой — вместо ответа оставьте комментарий под вопросом и позвольте другим более опытным участникам оставить качественный ответ, решающий поставленную проблему;
Ваш ответ сгенерирован нейросетью (GPT) — публикация созданных GPT и ChatGPT ответов недопустима! Помните об этом! Предоставьте возможность поиска ответа с помощью нейросети самому спрашивающему. Публикуя непроверенный ответ нейросети вы тем самым снижаете планку качества сайта Stack Overflow и подрываете к нему доверие! Является ли хорошим тоном публикация ответов, за которые вы не ручаетесь? Вопрос риторический.


Адаптация ответов других пользователей (включая переводы с сайта enSO) допустима, но нужно соблюдать грань между адаптацией и плагиатом. Указывайте ссылку на первоисточник и автора ответа.
Вы должны понимать, что повышение рейтинга с помощью плагиата является недопустимым и наказывается путём удаление ответа или применением более строгих санкций согласно пользовательскому соглашению.
4. Как написать хороший вопрос/ответ?
Написание текста на Stack Overflow, как в учёбе и профессиональной деятельности, требует:

Грамотного изложения мыслей;
Соблюдений правил русского языка: орфографии, пунктуации, грамматики и т. д.;
Структурированности и красоты визуального оформления (не забывайте разбивать текст на абзацы, не пишите его "сплошняком").

Сайт поддерживает Markdown и прочие возможности форматирования текста/кода. Ознакомиться со всеми инструментами более подробно вы можете в Справке по форматированию.
Перед публикацией вашего вопроса/ответа убедитесь, что вы привели все данные и подробности, а также убедитесь в том, что ваш код не был обрезан из-за неверного форматирования.
Форматирование вашего кода должно выглядеть так:
```
<...>
```

А не так:
```<...>```

Иначе существует вероятность того, что ваш текст будет обрезан!
Однострочное форматирование фрагмента небольшого кода в одну строку выглядит так:
`<...>`

5. Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками
Это что называется основа основ. @Akina предоставил хорошую адаптацию вопроса на enSO Meta (English Stack Overflow Meta).
Если вкратце:

Никому не захочется "пробегаться глазами" в поиске вашей ошибки;
Будет трудно воспроизвести код тому, кто пытается вам помочь;
Вы оказываете "медвежью услугу" тому, кто попытается предоставить вам исправленный код, поскольку это ему нужно будет конвертировать его в текст;
Такой "код" в виде скрина будет трудно изменять/дополнять, а всё в картинку не поместить;
Подумайте о тех, кто будет читать ваш вопрос не с ПК, а с другого устройства — у них изображение может исказиться.

6. Оставляйте описание к ссылкам
Цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом на случай, если ссылка станет недоступной или навсегда закрытой.
Это касается как вопросов, так и ответов. Представьте, вы выложили код на какой-либо сайт. А что если этот сайт "упадёт"? Или если прекратят его поддержку? Как в таком случае люди смогут ознакомиться с вашей проблемой/решением?
Логично, что вы можете спросить: "А как быть, если у меня проект на X строк кода? Его же сюда не уместить!"
А вот ответ на этот вопрос содержится в следующем пункте...
7. Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?
Пожалуйста, убедитесь в том, что ваша проблема воспроизводима. Другие пользователи не смогут помочь вам с вашей проблемой, если она возникает только на вашем устройстве и нигде более.
Не пишите "простыни" кода. Никому не будет удобно разворачивать ваш проект у себя, воссоздавая различные зависимости. Stack Overflow не "палочка-выручалочка", которая сама найдёт проблему в вашем многостраничном коде (на это есть различные GPT) — ваш код смотрят люди, не вовлечённые ранее в вашу проблему.
Локализуйте вашу проблему в конкретном блоке кода/методе/классе/зависимости — вот его и опубликуйте в тексте вопроса (не забудьте перед этим удалить чувствительную информацию: токены, персональные и иные секретные данные, не предназначенные для публичного доступа).
Если вы думаете, что для более быстрого решения вашей проблемы будет именно предоставление полного кода, то предоставьте ссылку на ваш проект (например, на GitHub и иные ресурсы) в качестве дополнительной информации.
8. Соблюдайте нормы поведения
Не забывайте про культурные нормы: не допускайте оскорблений в адрес участников, нецензурных выражений в вопросах/ответах/коде и провокационных заявлений, способных задеть чувства других или вызвать нетерпимость.
За нарушение норм поведения ваша учётная запись будет временно заблокирована, а также и удалена в случае неоднократных нарушений.
Избегайте развёрнутых дискуссий касаемо конкретных вопросов/ответов: вместо комментариев используйте чат-комнаты на Stack Exchange и Stack Exchange Meta.
9. Не нарушайте механизмы работы сайта
Помните о том, что на сайтах Stack есть система репутации и привилегий. К примеру, вы не можете опубликовать комментарий к вопросу/ответу другого участника пока не достигните репутации в размере 50 баллов.
При последующих нарушениях этих и других правил к вам могут быть применены более серьёзные ограничительные меры.

Не публикуйте ответы, не являющиеся таковыми — это нарушение правил сайта. Если вы опубликовали ответ, являющийся комментарием, то он подлежит удалению модераторами (пользователями со значком "⧫" возле отображаемого имени).
Если вы хотите задать дополнительный вопрос автору вопроса/ответа или написать "Вы уже решили данную проблему?" (вопросы такого рода не стоит задавать ввиду своей очевидности, поскольку проблема будет решена только после публикации ответа автором/другими пользователями или выяснением причин проблемы в комментариях), то не нужно публиковать комментарий в качестве ответа.
Наберите 50 баллов репутации, после чего вы спокойно сможете писать комментарии кому угодно и где угодно.
Как можно набрать баллы репутации описано в разделе справки "Что такое репутация? Как можно её заработать (и потерять)?", а также в авторской статье "Что такое репутация и как её заработать?".

Пожалуйста, после публикации вопроса постарайтесь дождаться ответа от других пользователей. Не "дублируйте" и не "забрасывайте" ваш вопрос.
Не забудьте принять ответ после того, как другим пользователем (или вами самим) был опубликован ответ — принятие ответа показывает другим, что он полезен и решил вашу проблему.
Не пишите автору под ответом комментарии по типу "Спасибо!"/"Выручили!"/"Это мне помогло!" — на сайтах Stack принято благодарить авторов принятием ответа и/или голосованием "за" по нему.

Пожалуйста, не вносите изменения в ответ, в котором вы приводите решение вашей проблемы. Также не публикуйте вопрос, в котором уже содержится текст ответа. Для этого есть отдельная галочка "Ответить на собственный вопрос" под публикуемым вами вопросом.
После решения вашего вопроса (либо самостоятельно, либо с помощью комментариев других пользователей), пожалуйста, не удаляйте текст вопроса и не меняйте заголовок на [Вопрос закрыт].
После решения вашей проблемы вы можете:

Опубликовать свой ответ


 Удалить свой вопрос



Учтите, что удаление вашего вопроса может в будущем негативно сказаться на быстроту решения аналогичной проблемы у других пользователей — подумайте о них!



Заключение
Многие из этих правил применимы к остальным сайтам Stack.
Пожалуйста, соблюдайте правила сайта Stack Overflow на русском! Помните о том, что неправомерные действия могут привести к нежелательным последствиям и ограничениям по отношению к вам.
Повторимся, что вы можете более подробно ознакомиться с правилами сайта Stack Overflow на русском в разделах "Тур", "Справка", "Привилегии", а также в статьях с меткой "faq" на Stack Overflow на русском Meta.
Мы надеемся, что данная статья помогла вам понять принципы и механизмы работы Stack Overflow на русском, и пользование этим сайтом будет приносить вам положительный опыт!

Сами то как думаете, какой процент новичков одолеет этот текст, когда его мучает желание задать волнующий именно его вопрос и тут же получить понятный ответ?

@avp, процент и не важен, главное, что такая статья просто есть. Эта статья больше не для пользователей, которые пришли решить свою проблему, а для тех, кто хочет развиваться и делиться знаниями на Stack Overflow. Для тех, кого просто нужно подтолкнуть в правильном направлении: https://i.sstatic.net/7h2MYPeK.png

Блажен кто верует...  (вы все это с разной активностью возобновляете постоянно в течении последних 5 лет. Результат сами найдете или опять ссылочку привести?) Очевидно же, что корень проблемы в "базе знаний" для коня сферического (точнее, в бабле, которое владельцы хотят слупить, продавая под каким-то соусом наши ответы (соус выбирается в зависимости от того с кем торгуются) ),  вместо нацеленности на быструю конкретную помощь конкретным людям

Если это остается в таком объеме, как минимум, надо порядок переделать, чтобы шли сначала основы, затем - более продвинутое. Первым должно идти "На какую тему можно задавать вопрос", затем "Как задать хороший вопрос", затем все остальное. Бессмысленно грузить грузить читателя, например, описаниями к ссылкам, если он может вообще еще не понял в общих чертах как работает сайт.

@avp не обесценивайте пожалуйста. Люди стараются и делают хорошее дело. Можете предложить более хорошее место для приложение сил - предлагайте! :-)
