Могу ли я узнать правила данного сайта
я не могу найти правила данного сайта подскажите пожалуйста.

Среди иконок справа вверху страницы есть ?. Жми на нее и читай.

вот главные: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct

Вам всё правильно озвучили люди сверху ↑. Как доп. чтиво могу посоветовать: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/14437

Конечено, же, Справка
5 минутное видео посмотрите, это 90% успеха. Остальное можно поискать по ссылкам в этой справке.
Обращайте внимания на подсказки в правой части сайта когда задаете вопрос. Там подсказки и по темам какие вопросы задавать и по темам редактирования вопроса/ответа.
В остальном вам сообщество подскажет. Если что-то не так, вам расскажут и в этом нет ничего страшного, если один из ваших вопросов закроют или оценят в минус. Вернитесь к справке, исправьте что вам подсказали и просто начните пользоваться и быстро привыкнете к местному, достаточно специфическому (и в этом есть своя прелесть), сообществу.
